# why are changes in localStorage not updated until refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to using localStorage and I am trying to use localStorage to store the login state so the logout button will appear if the user is logged in and the login button will appear if the user is logged out.

Why localStorage isn't being changed before the redirect if it is being called before the redirect? When I click the login button in the login component the localStorage should be updated and the logout navbar link in app.js should be shown but it isn't shown until I refresh the page. Why does this happen and how can I make the logout button be shown right when I redirect to a the new page?

login.component.js

```
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.userdata = {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
        };
        services.userlogin(this.userdata).then(res => {
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    console.log("Is mounted")
                    if (res === "Successfully authenticated user") {
                        // store the user in localStorage
                        console.log("changed");
                        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', "true") -> loggedIn is set to true
                        localStorage.setItem('isloggingIn', "false") -> isLoggingIn is set to false
                        localStorage.setItem('username', this.userdata.username)
                    }
                    this.setState({errormessage: res, username:'', password:''});
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Is unmounted")
                }
        })
    }
    error()
    {
        if (this.state.errormessage === "Successfully authenticated user") {
            // store the user in localStorage
            return (<Redirect from="/login-component" to={{pathname: '/ShopDetail', state: this.state}}/>); -> Redirects to ShopDetail page but logout button isn't shown 

        }
        else{
            return (<span className="span">{this.state.errormessage}</span>);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="div">
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="formWidth">
                    <Form.Group className="group" controlId="Username">
                        <Form.Label style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>Username</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChangeusername}/>
                        {this.state.usernameerrormessage.length > 0 &&
                        <span className="span">{this.state.usernameerrormessage}</span>}
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="group" controlId="Password">
                        <Form.Label style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChangepassword}/>
                        {this.state.passworderrormessage.length > 0 &&
                        <span className="span">{this.state.passworderrormessage}</span>}
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="danger" size="lg" block="block" type="submit"> Login </Button>
                </Form>
                {this.error()}

            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

APP.js

```
constructor(){
    this.state = {isLoggingIn: localStorage.getItem('isloggingIn'), isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') ;
}
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isLoggingIn: localStorage.getItem('isloggingIn'), isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') });
    }
const {isLoggingIn, isLoggedIn} = this.state;
<Nav className="ml-auto">
          <Nav>
               {isLoggedIn==="false" && isLoggingIn==="false" && <Link to={'/login-component'} onClick={this.login} className="nav-link">Login</Link>}
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
               {isLoggedIn==="false" && isLoggingIn==="false" && <Link to={'/createuser-component'} className="nav-link">Sign up</Link>}
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
               {isLoggedIn==="true" && isLoggingIn==="false" && <Link to={'/'} onClick={this.logout} className="nav-link">Logout</Link>} -> ***isLoggedIn is set to true and isLoggingIn is set to false in async userlogin function but the change is not reflected here unless the page is refreshed***
          </Nav>
   </Nav>
```

I have been trying to fix this for many days now but I really don't understand why this is happening at all.

Comment: You are not updating the state in App.js right? You need to setState in App.js when you set the localStorage item, otherwise App.js cannot know about the change

Comment: I didn't add that part but I am updating the state in App.js using setState in componentDidMount().

Comment: The rhetorical question would then be: will App.js re-mount when you update the localStorage in a sub component? Hint: the answer is NO

Comment: That is my question though, how can I make the app.js rerender using the updated localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass down a function reference from App.js to the sub component. This function takes a new state value and executes setState. In the sub component you can then call this function with the new value

Comment: Would you pass a function with a parameter through props to the login component through the route? I tried that before but I was never able to pass any functions from my parent app component to the login sub component.

Comment: You only ever pass the function name (reference) and then call the function with the parameter inside the sub component

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is not reactive, so after `Successfully authenticated user` you need to `setState`

```js
if (res === "Successfully authenticated user") {
    // store the user in localStorage
    console.log("changed");
    localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', "true") -> loggedIn is set to true
    localStorage.setItem('isloggingIn', "false") -> isLoggingIn is set to false
    localStorage.setItem('username', this.userdata.username)

    // calling this.setState here
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      isLoggingIn: false,
      username: this.userdata.username,
    });
}
```

But the better choice will be updating `localStorage` whenever `state` is changed. I am not expert at React and not sure what is the best way to handle it.

```js
// set state on successful auth
if (res === "Successfully authenticated user") {
    // calling this.setState here
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      isLoggingIn: false,
      username: this.userdata.username,
    });
}

// update localStorage when state changes
componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
    if (prevState.loggedIn !== this.state.loggedIn) {
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', this.state.loggedIn)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to update the localStorage in login.component.js and then the app.js will get the updated localstorage and add a logout link to the navbar. The state that I want to be changed is inside app.js not login.component.js.